# Javascript record keystroke timings

Tags: javascript, jquery, record, timing, keystroke

I want to record the time between each keystroke (just one key to start with, the 'A' key) in millseconds.
After the user finishes his thing he can submit and check out the timings between each key stroke. Like:

1: 500
2: 300
3: 400
4: 500
5: 100
6: 50
7: 50
8: 25

I believe this is possible with Javascript, is it?

Comment: How accurate does the timing need to be?  http://ejohn.org/blog/accuracy-of-javascript-time/

Comment: Around 5 milliseconds. Its just for personal use, so I don't have to support all kind of browsers.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: @Brad you can now use window.performance.now() for high-precision reporting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure:

```
var times = [];

// add an object with keycode and timestamp
$(document).keyup(function(evt) {
    times.push({"timestamp":evt.timeStamp,
                "keycode":evt.which})
});

// call this to get the string
function reportTimes() {
    var reportString = "";
    for(var i = 0; i < times.length - 1; ++i) {
         reportString += (i+1) + ": " + (times[i+1].timestamp - times[i].timestamp) + " ";
    }
    return reportString; // add this somewhere or alert it
}
```

I added the keycode just in case you wanted it later; it's not necessary for your exact problem statement.

---

**Clarification from comments discussion:**

The `for` loop only goes to up to `times.length - 2` (since `i` is always strictly less than `times.length - 1`), so there is no issue about `times[i+1]` being outside the bounds of the array. For example, if you do five key presses and therefore have a `times` array with five elements (indexed from `0` to `4`):

```
1st pass: times[1].timestamp - times[0].timestamp
2nd pass: times[2].timestamp - times[1].timestamp
3rd pass: times[3].timestamp - times[2].timestamp
4th pass: times[4].timestamp - times[3].timestamp
```

Then the loop terminates, because setting `i` to `4` triggers the termination condition:

```
= i < times.length - 1
= 4 < 5 - 1
= 4 < 4
= false  [i cannot be set to 4 by this loop]
```

Thus, `times[i+1]` is always a validly indexed element, because `i` is at most one less than the maximum index.

Comment: Thanks. Only the last added value cannot substract to the next value since it doesn't excist.

Comment: The script only runs while i is less than times.length - 1, i.e. the last i index is length - 2, so there is always a next value.

Comment: You posted a comment earlier about only seeing four records for five presses: that is the expected result.  *Five* presses produce *four* time intervals *between* them.

Comment: Each press has its value. But if you press five times you get only four values since the last value cannot substract itself to a next value. Am I seeing this right?

Comment: A example for 5 presses: times[2].timestamp - times[1].timestamp -> Valid --- times[3].timestamp - times[2].timestamp -> Valid --- times[4].timestamp - times[3].timestamp -> Valid ---   times[5].timestamp - times[4].timestamp -> Valid ---  times[6].timestamp - times[5].timestamp -> times[6].timestamp doesnt excist.

Comment: First: arrays in JavaScript are indexed starting from 0, not 1.  Second: the last operation in your example never takes place.  The loop stops on the second-to-last element. `times[1].timestamp - times[0].timestamp` is the first interval and `times[5].timestamp - times[4].timestamp` is the last.

Comment: I edited my answer. Do you need further clarification? All five key presses are being processed correctly, and you should see all four time intervals that occur between the key presses.

Comment: I understand. I am making a tool wich you can use to create a sequence of bangs in a order. I use setTimeout for each cue that is being used to give it self a delay. Now if you want 5 bangs and press 5 times in the melody you like you only get 4. Or you need to press the key a extra time now. You understand what I mean?